# XPCollection Not Loading

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

I have an XPCollection in one of my Classes. It's an XPCollection of another class. When I run the app the XPCollection does not get Loaded. I can see it clearly in my breakpoint when debugging. Here is the code I am using in my  Object. :

```
  private XPCollection<LimitAllocationTotals> _LimitAllocationTotals;

    public XPCollection<LimitAllocationTotals> LimitAllocationTotals   LimitAllocationTotals
    {
        get
        {


            if (LimitAllocations.IsLoaded && LimitAllocations != null)
            {
                UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork();
                _LimitAllocationTotals = new XPCollection<LimitAllocationTotals>(uow, new BinaryOperator("Oid", Guid.Empty));
                _LimitAllocationTotals.Session = this.Session;
                foreach (LimitAllocation allocation in LimitAllocations)
                {
                    LimitAllocationTotals allocationTotals = new LimitAllocationTotals(this.Session);

                    allocationTotals.MTMLimit += allocation.MTMLimit;
                    allocationTotals.ARLimit += allocation.ARLimit;
                    allocationTotals.Volume += allocation.Volume;
                    allocationTotals.MaxTenor = allocation.MaxTenor;
                    allocationTotals.SourceEntity = allocation.SourceEntity;
                    allocationTotals.Commodity = allocation.Commodity;
                    allocationTotals.ConvertedVolume = allocation.ConvertedVolume;
                    _LimitAllocationTotals.Add(allocationTotals);

                }


                foreach (LimitExtension extension in LimitExtensions)
                {
                    if (extension.ExpirationDate >= DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        LimitAllocationTotals searchAllocation = null;
                        foreach (LimitAllocationTotals allocation in _LimitAllocationTotals)
                        {
                            if (allocation.SourceEntity != null && allocation.SourceEntity.Oid.Equals(extension.SourceEntity.Oid))
                            {
                                searchAllocation = allocation;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (searchAllocation == null)
                        {
                            searchAllocation = new LimitAllocationTotals(this.Session);
                            searchAllocation.SourceEntity = extension.SourceEntity;
                            _LimitAllocationTotals.Add(searchAllocation);
                        }

                        searchAllocation.MTMLimit += extension.MTMLimit;
                        searchAllocation.ARLimit += extension.ARLimit;
                        searchAllocation.Volume += extension.Volume;
                        searchAllocation.Commodity = extension.Commodity;
                        searchAllocation.MaxTenor += extension.MaxTenor;
                       // searchAllocation.CalculateMeasureConversion(_Commodity, _VolumeUnit);
                        //searchAllocation.VolumeUnit = extension.VolumeUnit;

                    }
                }
            }
            return _LimitAllocationTotals;
        }
        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue("LimitAllocationTotals", ref _LimitAllocationTotals, value);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Normally you don't need to check the LimitAllocations.IsLoaded. LimitAllocations collection will load whenever used.

Answer (score 0):

An `XPCollection` is loaded on demand. From [the documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#corelibraries/clsDevExpressXpoXPCollectiontopic):

> In most cases, a collection needs to be created to access objects of a
>   specific type from a data store. The `XPCollection` class implements
>   delayed loading, i.e. it's populated with persistent objects from the
>   data store on demand. For instance, you can create an `XPCollection`
>   instance, that is marked to contain custom Person objects. The
>   collection, however, will be populated with Person objects from a data
>   store only when the collection's contents is accessed.

You can force the load from the data store by calling `XPCollection.Load()` but generally [this should not be necessary](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#corelibraries/DevExpressXpoXPBaseCollection_Loadtopic).

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize that collection safely on OnLoaded method or you can check IsLoading and IsSaving property value in property getter and return if any of them is true. Only when (IsLoading || IsSaving)==false you can load collection from DB safely.

you can try this on getter method;

```
public XPCollection<LimitAllocationTotals> LimitAllocationTotals 
{
        get
        {
            if (IsLoading || IsSaving)
                return _LimitAllocationTotals;

            //  .... your codes
        }
}
```